# Is it possible to add hyperlinks between sequence diagrams, in UMLet

Tags: sequence-diagram, umlet

I'm looking to make a sequence diagram, using UMLet, for multiple scenarios, but all of them having same "core" functionality. So, I was thinking of defining this core functionality as a separate sequence diagram and link it to the individual ones.
Is it possible in UMLet? If not, can any of you suggest an alternative for this?

Answer (score 0):

UMLet does not have this hyperlink feature that was [requested](https://github.com/umlet/umlet/issues/122) in 2013 and is still marked as open.

The reason is most probably because it would conflict with its UI of clicking on an element to edit it, but certainly as well due to the difficulty to offer the desired behavior across the different environments.

**Not related**:  Interestingly,  plantUML [has this feature](https://forum.plantuml.net/542/ability-to-define-hyperlink-on-diagram-elements). Unlike UMLet, plantUML is not interactive diagramming put produces a rendered diagram from a textual input.  So the hyperlink is easier to implement: whatever the environment, it is sufficient to render the hyperlink in the output artefact and let the client environment operate the link if the output format supports it (yes in SVG, no in PNG or ascii art).

Comment: thanks for your info about plantUML, @Christophe. I will explore that.